# How to use vmware and docker on Windows 10 at the same time

Tags: windows, docker, vmware

I've been using vmware on Windows 10 for some time now.

Recently I installed docker on Windows 10, then vmware stopped working.

I can switch hypervisor off to make vmware back to work, but that disabled docker service.

Now is there a way to keep both working at the same time ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Docker toolbox otherwise no way as i know

Comment: Thanks ! as it's a legacy solution, I have to find another machine to test it out.